# К постоянной ссылке в Wordpress добавляется "-2". Как сделать без этого?

Tags: wordpress

У меня возникла такая проблема. К постоянной ссылке в Wordpress добавляется "-2". Как сделать без этого? На данный момент у меня
virtual/museums-2/, а хотелось сделать virtual/museums. Шаблон страницы у меня назван museums. Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> К постоянной ссылке в Wordpress добавляется "-2".

ВП добавляет цифровые окончания при наличии существующего слага. Учитывается и в корзине.
Поэтому если уверен, что поста с таким слагом нет, то нужно очистить корзину.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Очень выручили